# Queries to track kubeevents

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

queries which will allow us  to track kubeevents and get notified if there are any issues with the pods being scheduled or killed..

Answer (score 1):

YAML is not a scripting language, it is a data markup language like JSON or XML. So no, but perhaps you meant to ask something else?

Comment: Do you mean you want to run an alerting system? If so, the standard tool is Prometheus and kube-state-metrics.

Comment: need some queries to track important KubeEvents, notified if there are issues with PODs being Scheduled or Killed

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in [eventrouter](https://github.com/heptiolabs/eventrouter).

It is a service for handling your Kubernetes Events, e.g. log them or send them to any *sink* e.g. Kafka.